# Number lines and modulus C++

Tags: c++, arrays, modulus

I am trying to make the opposite of case 3. So the idea is that you can say "x amount of days from sat will be **_" . This works well in my `case 3` so I figured the same would work if you wanted to solve "x days before sat will be _**". Now my `case 4` only works till a input of 6 then you enter negative numbers which I did not thick about when making this... And my program is based off a array `char dayChar[7][4] {"Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};` so has you can see `case 4` does not really work. 
Any suggestions on how to what I could do that would work? 
Thanks a ton in advance.

```
case 3: // Add days
                cout << "Day selected is " << day << endl;
                cout << "How many days would you like to add?" << endl;
                cin >> addOrSub;

                temp = (dayNum + addOrSub);
                dayNum = (temp % 7);

                cout << addOrSub << " days from " << day << " will be " << dayChar[dayNum] << endl; 


                break;

            case 4: // Subtract days
                cout << "Day selected is " << day << endl;
                cout << "How many days would you like to subtract?" << endl;
                cin >> addOrSub;

                temp = (dayNum - addOrSub);
                dayNum = (temp % 7);

                cout << addOrSub << " before " << day << " was " << dayChar[dayNum] << endl;
```

Comment: You could first subtract a multiple of 7 from daynum, and then add the absolute value of number of days to subtract. Then it would be like case 3. In other words, for case 4, just temporarily reset the daynum to an earlier time so that you are adding not subtracting days.

Comment: dayNum = ((temp % 7) + 7) % 7;

Comment: @d0c and synapitk, great suggestions. Btw d0c That seems to work I am testing it now. I'll you know if it does you should post that as a answer. :)

Comment: @d0c yes I do think that works wow! Somethings I just don't think in math like that God bless people like you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to do: `dayNum = ((temp % 7) + 7) % 7;`

Since `temp % 7` is guaranteed to be greater than -7, adding 7 is guaranteed to give you a positive number, equivalent to the original (modulo 7). The resulting number, though, may be greater than 7, which is why an additional modulo operation is necessary.